# how to use sytoscape.js in dotnetnuke module for creating graph

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, cytoscape.js

I using dotnetnuke and I need to create a web base online graph in a dotnetnuke module. How to create a graph in asp.net c# web application using Cytoscape.js and totally how to use Cytoscape.js in asp.net web application?

Comment: excuse me I am not good in English

Comment: Which "graph" from https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery is closest  to what you need to create?

Comment: You ought to be able to use it just as you would any other JS lib -- along with your other JS code.